# extension $ is not defined manifest v3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

now script js add from background.js

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: {tabId: tabID, allFrames: true},
            files: ['script.js']
})
```

script.js

```
var jsURL = chrome.runtime.getURL("jquery/jquery.min.js");

var jq = document.createElement('script');

jq.src = jsURL;

document.head.prepend(jq);


window.onload = function(){
    var t = setTimeout(function(){
       $.noConflict(true);
       $("p").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
    }, 5000);
}
```

manifest v3

```
"web_accessible_resources": [{
        "resources": ["jquery/jquery.min.js", "css/style.css" ],
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "extension_ids": []
    }],
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

how inject jquery in manifest 3 ?

Comment: Do you want to use jquery in the popup.html or on the webpage?

Comment: or on the webpage

Comment: Then you don't need any of the current code. You probably need chrome.scripting.executeScript or a content script declared in manifest.json. Describe what it is that you want to perform on the web page and how/where this process is activated/triggered.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I wrote in the starting topic, I need to insert jquery into any open page. But I get an error message: , I tried url from other sources like googleapis, the result is the same, the script itself with the extension url is fine added to the head, but I get this error, why?

Comment: You need to clarify how, where, what for, this jquery will be used because just inserting jquery into all pages is harmful and meaningless.

Comment: I want to understand how this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

How about this.

popup.html

```
<script src="jquery/jquery.min.js"/>
<script src="script.js"/>
```

Comment: i changed the order by adding script in background.js now if i add jquery in popup i get jquery on my popup but i need injection on any page.